# Photoshop scripting with javascript: variable won't assign

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, photoshop

I've just started trying my hand at some photoshop scripting with javascript and run into this problem with a switch statement - code below:

```
var document = app.activeDocument;
var activeLayer = document.activeLayer;
if(activeLayer.kind == LayerKind.TEXT) {
    var textItem = activeLayer.textItem;
    var newText = "null";
    var iString = "null";
    for (var i=0; i<=720; i++) {
        switch (i)
        {
        case (i<=60):
          if (i==60) {
            iString = "00";
          } else {
           iString = i.toString();
          }
          newText = "00:" + iString;
          break;
        case (etc...):
          etc...
        break;
    }
    textItem.contents = newText;
    var saveFile = new File("/Users/Family/Desktop/wallpaper-clock/lake_" + newText);
    document.saveAs(saveFile);
}
```

}

This doesn't throw any errors in photoshop, but newText is staying as 'null' and not getting set to anything within the switch statement. It's as if the whole switch is just doing nothing! It might just be a stupid syntax error (been using Objective-C for a while!) or possibly scope? Anyway any suggestions would be really helpful!

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you setting things to `"null"`? That's just a string constant, unlike `null` which is a specific language primitive value type.

Comment: This I know, it's just to test it out so that something gets printed in photoshop and I can tell what's going on (that was the idea anyway...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how JavaScript `switch ... case` statements work.  The `case` expressions are evaluated statically.

Basically you need `if` instead of `switch`:

```
  if (i <= 60) {
   // ...
  }
  else if (i <= whatever) {
   // ...
  }
  // ... and so on ...
```

Also, you almost certainly want the constant `null` and not the string `"null"`.

Comment: Correct and nice catch! Ref: "NOTE Evaluating CaseClause does not execute the associated StatementList. It simply evaluates the Expression and returns the value, which the CaseBlock algorithm uses to determine which StatementList to start executing." - http://es5.github.io/#x12.11

Comment: You _can_ do `switch(true)` (and languages like Ruby or Coffeescript even facilitate by making `(true)` implicit), but yeah, `if/else if` is often more readable.